# Create a ring of points around the midpoint of an arbitrarily positioned cylinder

Tags: three.js

Experimenting with ideas for a game and want to create a ring of points perpendicular to the midpoint of an arbitrarily positioned cylinder.

I have it partially working here: http://jsfiddle.net/callum/v0can3t0/ with random start/end points but positioning the ring correctly over the midpoint (blue sphere) is not working.

Maybe the axis generation from my start and end points of cylinder is wrong?

```
var axis = look_at_pos.clone().sub(start_pos).normalize();
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Inevitably, having struggled with it for hours, I figured it out as soon as I posted it.

I have to cross the point with the axis before rotation.

```
vector.cross(axis)
```

Updated & working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/callum/v0can3t0/1/

Apologies if answering own question is bad form but I wanted to leave the information out there.

== edit ==

Actually - there is still something wrong - porting this code into my app results the ring being scaled to a different size depending on the location it was created - must be missing a factor somewhere.